# Android Activity SingleTask launch mode = separate own memory

Tags: android

I have an android application that can take a photo from device's camera. 
The photo has a high quality and big size, this photo can be displayed in my activity (PhotoDisplayActivity). I'm aware of `OutOfMemoryException`, it is included in my task so I tried to change the launch mode of `PhotoDisplayActivity` to "single task". If I separate `PhotoDisplayActivity` to another task, does this separate also memory and avoid `OutOfMemoryException` ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Tasks control things like the behavior of the BACK button and the recent-tasks list.

Running that activity in a separate *process* will give you an independent heap, but not running it in an independent task.

Comment: Separate process? By means of moving ``PhotoActivity`` to a new android project?

Comment: @Glenn: No, by using `android:process` in the manifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc

Comment: seems like new to my mind, I have no idea, lol, Do you have a tutorial for that? :)

Comment: @Glenn: No, because using multiple processes in Android is generally an anti-pattern. Your scenario is one of the few where it might be justified. If you happen to be supporting only API Level 11 and higher, you could use `android:largeHeap="true"` instead.

Comment: I see, thanks for the great info, I should subscribe to your book :)